# Using SCM to synchronize PyDev eclipse projects between different computer

Tags: python, eclipse, version-control, synchronization, pydev

I use eclipse to write python codes using pydev. So far I have been using dropbox to synchronize my workspace.

However, this is far from ideal. I would like to use github (or another SCM platform) to upload my code so I can work with it from different places.

However, I have found many tutorials kind of daunting... Maybe because they are ready for projects shared between many programers

Would anyone please share with me their experience on how to do this? Or any basic tutorial to do this effectively?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use mercurial. I picked it because it seemed easier. But is is only easiER.

There is mercurial eclipse plugin.

Save a copy of your workspace and maybe your eclipse folder too before daring it :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion: I have found a few videos on youtube and it seems easier for the simple tasks I want to do. One more question: Do you know of any set up where eclipse will synchronize/back up on a schedule?

Answer (score 0):

Well, personally I use GitHub or BitBucket (using Git in both cases). I do have EGit installed which I use for history and comparisons, but usually my workflow goes around using the git command line (mostly using mu-repo: http://fabioz.github.io/mu-repo/ as I'm usually dealing with multiple git repositories).

So, my recommendation is initially following something as http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/ only in the command line (without even creating any branches, just `clone`, `change files`, `add/commit` in your master branch and then in your other repo `pull` things you've done). After you get used to doing that (which should be simple if you keep only on those points), you can try to go into checking diffs, stashing, creating feature branches, etc.

p.s.: I do recommend you have some backup initially, just to be on the safe side (afterwards, git itself will be your backup).

Comment: Thank you Fabio for your comment. I understand github is the way to go speciallly if I want to share some of my codes. However, I still have to get familiar with its application

Answer (score 0):

I use bitbucket coupled with mercurial. That is my repository is on bitbucket and i pull and psuh to it from mercurial within eclipse
For my backup i have an independent carbonite process going to net back all hard disk files. But I imagine there is a clever free programatic way to do so. If one knew how to write the appropriate scripts.

Glad the first suggestion was helpful .you are wise to bite the bullet and get this in place now. ;)